# ImportError: cannot import name 'ranked_blast_output_schema' from 'param'

Tags: importerror

I am just getting started on Python, though I know a bit of R. I want to replicate something someone has already done. I am receiving this error on one of my kernels on Jupyter and I don't immediately know what to do about it. Does anyone have any input or experience with it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 8, in <module>
    from param import ranked_blast_output_schema, blast_outfmt6_schema
ImportError: cannot import name 'ranked_blast_output_schema' from 'param' (/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/param/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lca_analysis.py", line 52, in <module>
    if ("~" in blast_results["query"].iloc[0]):
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 894, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1443, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: Since the error is about some `ranked_blast_output_schema` it would be difficult to help you more without any more context.

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay. I am replicating a Jupyter notebook and I was told to run this link on bash.

```
lca_analysis.py --blast_type nt --fpath s3://org_name/contigs/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/blast_nt.m9 --filtered_blast_path s3://bucket_name/contig_quality/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/blast_nt_filtered.m9 --excluded_contigs_path s3://bucket_name/contig_quality/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/exclude_contigs_nt.txt --outpath s3://bucket_name/contig_quality/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/lca_nt.m9 --read_count_path s3://bucket_name/contigs/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/contig_stats.json --verbose True
```

But then, I had this error

```
Read counts have been loaded: s3://bucket_name/contigs/CMS001_002_Ra_S1/contig_stats.json| elapsed time: 0.73 seconds
/var/folders/ns/gdtc2hvx1g13_29wct4qkhd80000gq/T/tmp3m3k6w9o blast file downloaded to this tempfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 8, in <module>
    from param import ranked_blast_output_schema, blast_outfmt6_schema
ImportError: cannot import name 'ranked_blast_output_schema' from 'param' (/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/param/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lca_analysis.py", line 52, in <module>
    if ("~" in blast_results["query"].iloc[0]):
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 894, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Users/myaccount/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1443, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I had just used pip install param to get param, and the install went just fine.